# Take range slider values from array

Tags: jquery, arrays, jquery-mobile

I am using JQM 1.4.5 range slider and I want to take my values/steps directly from an array...
I couldn't find any solid way of doing this...

**My array**

```
var myArray = [ "0", "1", "6", "a", "F", "5B", "2x" ];
```

**My slider**

```
<input class="ui-hidden-accessible" type="range" name="rangeInput" id="rangeInput" value="0" data-show-value="true"/>
```

**UPDATE:**

*I know this can be done with jquery.ui slider but I am using this in a mobile app and I would like to avoid adding UI to it...*

**Working example with UI**

```js
var sizes = ["0", "1", "6", "a", "F", "5B", "2x"];

$("#slider").slider({
  min: 0,
  max: 7,
  slide: function(event, ui) {
      $(".rsize").text(sizes[ui.value]);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/dot-luv/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="demo">

<div id="slider"></div>

    <div class='rsize'></div>
</div>
```

Comment: what do you mean by custom values?

Comment: @omar Instead of 0 to 9 as it is now I want to add, let's say, 1,6,a,F,5B,2x as the values...how cand I do this? I need to be able to control each value for that range slider.

Comment: `type=range` accepts numbers only.

Comment: @omar I will have to disagree with you, I have seen a range-slider with 2W, 5W and so on just a couple of days ago, didn't think I would need it so I didn't pay attention to it...and now I can't find it again...

Comment: In that case you need to read values from a different array not from `min`/`max`.

Comment: @omar well I can give those up. But how can I read them from an array ? I can't picture the script...

Comment: @omar I have updated my question with the array and also did the same thing I needed but with jQuery UI...but I am interested of doing it without UI

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66647/discussion-between-omar-and-alin).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery Mobile's *slider widget* doesn't offer `slide` event. Instead, `change` event can be used to update *text* of the handle with a custom value from an array.

First, update `max` attribute of the *slider* based on `length` of your array of custom values and change the *text* of the handle.

```
var custom = ["0", "1", "6", "a", "F", "5B", "2x"];

$("#rangeInput").prop({
    max: custom.length - 1
}).closest(".ui-slider")
    .find(".ui-slider-handle")
    .text(custom[0]);
```

Then, listen to `change` event, based on *true value* retrieved, read your array and fetch the custom value.

```
$("#rangeInput").on("change", function () {
    var value = $(this).val(),
        button = $(this)
            .closest(".ui-slider")
            .find(".ui-slider-handle");
    setTimeout(function () { /* update text after jQM refreshes slider */
        button.text(custom[value]);
    }, 0);
});
```

Now the *true value* is a number; consider it an index of the *custom value* of your array.

```
var true_val = $("#rangeInput").val(),
    custom_value = custom[true_val];
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/0vaoLoq5/)**

Comment: Hey, can we talk inside the chatroom ? I wanna ask you something i really don't understand ..http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66647/discussion-between-omar-and-alin